# hive performance with many where clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive query

> select * from tbl where month(dt) = '06' and year(dt) = '2011'

I would like to whether whether there could be any benefit if I club both year and month and add a new udf for the same,

> select * from tbl where yearMonth(dt) = '201106'

I am a newbie in Hive and hence any thoughts on whether I need to go with new UDF is highly welcome.

Whether hive executes the results in sequential, first filter with 2011 and in that result filter with 06?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mappers should execute both filters on the data in one step.
you can always check this using the `explain` statement.
if you usually filter on years and months you should consider partitioning the table on those columns. that way the mappers will read only the relevant partitions and not the entire table.